# Datatype compatibility: int vs. nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using below sql statement to read and import data from excel spreadsheet to database table:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable] ([ColumnA], [ColumnB], [ColumnC], [ColumnD])
SELECT A.[AAA], A.[BBB], A.[CCC], A.[DDD] FROM OPENROWSET 
('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Temp\TestFile\01-TestFile.xlsx;HDR=YES', 'select * from [Sheet$]') AS A;
```

TestTable has four columns, only accepting integer datatypes. The import works well with numbers in the database spreadsheet. However, if for some reason there is a mistake in the file (i.e. there is text instead of digits), it fails and I get an error converting nvarchar to int datatype. Is there any way to ensure the upload still works - that text is ommitted and appears as NULL in the table?

Comment: Insert data into a staging table that only uses `NVARCHAR`, and use `TRY_CONVERT` and `TRY_PARSE` to conditionally attempt the conversions. Even with this error handling in T-SQL kinda sucks, though, so if this gets more complicated you may want to upgrade the process to use an actual ETL package like SSIS or a custom application.

Comment: Alternatively, you could add validation to the spreadsheet and stop being entering "numbers" like `'Steve'` or `24 April 2019'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try TRY_CAST as shown below. Works for SQL Server 2012+.

```
SELECT TRY_CAST('TEST' AS INT)
```

See more on [TRY_CAST (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: What would be the modified syntax based on provided example? I'm getting an incorrect syntax near 'AS' error when executing INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable] ([ColumnA], [ColumnB], [ColumnC], [ColumnD])
SELECT TRY_CAST([AAA], [BBB], [CCC], [DDD] AS INT) FROM OPENROWSET 
('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Temp\TestFile\01-TestFile.xlsx;HDR=YES', 'select * from [Sheet$]');

Comment: You should apply TRY_CAST for every field TRY_CAST([AAA] as int ] AAA, TRY_CAST([BBB] as int ] BBB, TRY_CAST([CCC] AS int] CCC, ….